# Google sign-in SDK 2.0.1 for iOS error

Tags: ios, objective-c, social-networking, google-signin

I'm trying to integrate the Google sign-in in my project for that i'm using 'Google sign-in SDK 2.0.1'.
I have follow the steps shown on developer.google site but when i click on the button it returns with error 'Unknown error' in `- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error`

I have integrated 2 url schemes and app-delegate,VC implementation as shown in tutorial

Here is the code for ViewController where i implement the Sign-in button

```objective-c
@interface ViewController () < GIDSignInUIDelegate,GIDSignInDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GIDSignInButton *btnSignin;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;

}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma mark - GIDSignInDelegate

- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error in signin %@",[error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------


- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
didDisconnectWithUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error did disconnect %@",[error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: just restarted the xcode and simulator and started working after it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the specific error code?  Generally, you will see a message returned along with the exception:

```
2015-06-18 16:36:49.463 SignInExample[20038:2727845] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Your app must support the following URL schemes: (null)'
```

A few things to help diagnose in the meantime:

- You might want to start from [the Google Sign-in quickstart](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start) by running `pod try Google` and use `[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError: &configureError];` to configure the project
- If you are not calling `configureWithError`, you should be setting the client ID, typically done in your AppDelegate, for example:

  `[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";`
- Look at the web browser address (if you're testing in the simulator) to make sure that the client ID is getting passed to the sign in flow
- Make sure to add the reversed client ID to your URL Schemes

Comment: app is not terminating , it dismiss the modal in one second after it appear when i click the sign in button
How can i check that web browser address ?
Thanks

Comment: Thanks , this may help other people in their startup of google sign in